# select products from specific category codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Products are available in following categories

```
product_id   category_id
     2            1,2
     3            1,3
     4            1,13
     2            2,5
```

I want to select products of specific category e.g. all products from category 2. what will be sql syntax

Comment: Its better to restructure your database rather than storing relations in single column learn about database normalization

Comment: I agree with @MKhalidJunaid as your database is not even 1st level normalize. while in your scenario it should be at least level 2. so you need to create m2m table for products and categories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FIND_IN_SET` for seach in comma separated values.

```
 $this->db->where("FIND_IN_SET( '$category_id' , category_ids) ");
```

So your whole query be like

```
$this->db->select();
$this->db->from('table_name');
$this->db->where("FIND_IN_SET( '$category_id' , category_ids) "); 
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `FIND_IN_SET` for search comma separated values.

```
    <?php
    $this->db->select();
    $this->db->from('table_name'); 
    $this->db->where(' FIND_IN_SET(category_ids, "' . $category_ids . '") > 0', NULL, false);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
    ?>
```

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple SQL query & use this in your model.

```
public function get_product_category($category_id)
{
     $query = "SELECT * FROM product_table WHERE category_id LIKE '%$categoryid%'";
     return $this->db->query($query, $category_id)->result();
}
```

It will find in your product table where `category_id` contain example `2`.

But, like M Khalid Junaid said, you better learn about database normalization.

For example : **Normalization Table**

This is your table before normalized, the product ID is duplicated on `2` how can if that is a primary key ? So, try to change your table to normalized table, it will help you so much.

```
product_id   category_id
     2            1,2
     3            1,3
     4            1,13
     2            2,5
```

This is a new table are normalized after creating a table named `group_table` or whatever. Then set `group_id` as a `primary_key`

```
group_id       product_id       category_id
    1               2                 1
    2               2                 2
    3               3                 1
    4               3                 3        
    5               4                 1
    6               4                 13
    7               2                 5
```

The query for find the product from category_id is more simple, just

`SELECT * FROM group_table WHERE category_id = $category_id`

or any condition that you wanted to create. Like if you wanted to get product name just `JOIN` the table from `product_table`

Comment: I think `WHERE category_id LIKE '%$categoryid%'` is dangerous because if you search for category `3` it will also return the record that has `category_id`= `1,13` because it contains `3`

Comment: Sure, so isn't is same if using `FIND_IN_SET` ?

Comment: `FIND_IN_SET` is for searching in comma separated values.

Comment: Ah okay, that is my fault for that. But i'll just keep the answers because normalization table is there. Thank you for you information @AhmedTaha. Because I never use `FIND_IN_SET`